# Self Signed SSL Connection - Android

Tags: android, ssl

I added the SSLFactory and the TrustManager classes as described [here](http://blog.synyx.de/2010/06/android-and-self-signed-ssl-certificates/).

I'm establishing a connection as following:

```
//does not work
String url = "https://waprd.uark.edu/web-apps/regr/scheduleofclasses/Main?strm=1123";
  //http://bektemirov.com/a/android.php?t=amurica   //simple http - works

HttpClient client = new DefaultHttpClient(clientConnectionManager, params);
HttpGet get = new HttpGet(url);
try {
  HttpResponse response = client.execute(get, context);
  HttpEntity entity = response.getEntity();

  String responseText = EntityUtils.toString(entity);
  Body.setText(responseText);

} catch (ClientProtocolException e) {
  // TODO Auto-generated catch block
  e.printStackTrace();
} catch (IOException e) {
  // TODO Auto-generated catch block
  e.printStackTrace();
}
```

Connection fails every time for this particular link. Direct me in the right direction, please?

Comment: What is the exception you get?What is the full stack trace?

Comment: Not trusted server certification:


`10-27 01:02:10.620: WARN/System.err(381): javax.net.ssl.SSLException: Not trusted server certificate`
`10-27 01:02:10.630: WARN/System.err(381):  at org.apache.harmony.xnet.provider.jsse.OpenSSLSocketImpl.startHandshake(OpenSSLSocketImpl.java:371)`
`10-27 01:02:10.630: WARN/System.err(381): at org.apache.harmony.xnet.provider.jsse.OpenSSLSocketImpl$SSLInputStream.<init>(OpenSSLSocketImpl.java:520)`
10-27 01:02:10.630: WARN/System.err(381): at org.apache.harmony.xnet.provider.jsse.OpenSSLSocketImpl.getInputStream(OpenSSLSocketImpl.java:461)`
...

Comment: The exception says that the certificate send by server is not trusted.Where is the code you configure the `SSLContext`?Please update the OP

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you initialize SSLContext, there is a parameter to pass TrustManager array where you can define your own TrustManager to accept all. Some of the key steps are listed below :

1. Subclass SSLSocketFactory
2. Customize TrustManager to accept all certificates in subclass of SSLSocketFactory.
3. Initialize SSLContext with the customized TrustManager in subclass of SSLSocketFactory.
4. Create parameterized DefaultHttpClient with HttpParams and ClientConnectionManager which uses SchemeRegistry where you can register 'https' with your subclass of SSLSocketFactory.

So that, all https response will be handled by your customized TrustManager class.